# XML transform recursive and attribute as node name

Tags: xml, xslt

I am having XML files in below format.

```
<Main>
    <root>
        <group firstname="daniel" secondname="creig">
            <a firstname="tin" secondname="tao"/>
                <b firstname="bella" secondname="james">
                    <c firstname="khadhar" secondname="abdul">
                        <d firstname="xiang" secondname="tin"/>
                    </c>
                </b>
        </group>
    </root>
</Main>
```

And I am trying to get the output like below.

```
<members>
    <member><id>group</id><firstname>daniel</firstname><secondname>creig</secondname></member>
    <member><id>a</id><firstname>tin</firstname><secondname>tao</secondname></member>
    <member><id>b</id><firstname>bella</firstname><secondname>james</secondname></member>
    <member><id>c</id><firstname>khadhar</firstname><secondname>abdul</secondname></member>
    <member><id>d</id><firstname>xiang</firstname><secondname>tin</secondname></member>
</members>
```

So far My XSL will be looking like this.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- Elements Section -->
<xsl:template match="/*/root/*">
<member>
    <id>
        <xsl:value-of select="local-name()" />  
    </id>
    <attr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" /> 
    </attr>
</member>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="(.)" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

All i need is to convert the nodes in XML tree of any depth to an array. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Nothing would work with that template as it isn't legal XML let alone XSLT. Where's the opening of 'node'! And what's 'id' for? Neither of them appears in your sample output. And where is the recursion required?

Comment: I have corrected my post. Recursion required,if xml node contains child node.

Comment: Please, provide the *complete* output you want. The currently provided wanted output only contains results from the first two levels of the hierarchy. We need to know what complete output is wanted, in order to better understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
   <members>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
   </members>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root//*">
    <member>
       <id><xsl:value-of select="local-name(.)" /></id>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
    </member>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root//@*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">
       <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: JLRishe's answer is correct with little modification. Thanks to all.